# ¿Por qué aparecen espacios en blanco a la derecha luego de hacer un update con RTrim sobre la misma columna?

Tags: sql-server

Quiero eliminar los espacios en blanco que sobran **despues** de un valor utilizando `RTRIM` pero estoy teniendo problemas con ello.

Por ejemplo, tengo una tabla llamada `Alumnos` con la columna `Nombre`. Nombre es de tipo `char(10)` y el primer valor es `'Juan'` .

Esto es lo que hago:

```
UPDATE Alumnos SET Nombre = (RTRIM(Nombre))
```

Para comprobar, hago el

```
SELECT * FROM Alumnos
```

copio y pego el valor `'Juan'` en un editor de textos y me doy cuenta que aún tiene los 6 espacios después del último caracter, es decir, la *n*.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Estoy usando SQL Server 2014

Comment: El campo debería ser de tipo `varchar`, para que no tenga ese comportamiento. Los campos `char` tienen un tamaño definido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como dice en la documentación para el tipo [`char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms176089.aspx):

> **char**
>   Datos de cadena no Unicode de ***longitud fija***.

O sea que, aunque estés usando menos caracteres que lo que la capacidad permite, el campo siempre tendrá una longitud fija llenandolo de espacios de ser necesario.

Parece que lo que realmente quieres es usar el tipo `varchar(10)` en vez de `char(10)`.

> **varchar**
>   Datos de cadena no Unicode de ***longitud variable***.

Comment: Ah ok ahora entiendo, muchas gracias!